# Unicorn.rb configuration depending on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

I've got a line in config/unicorn.rb that looks like so:

`working_directory "/SomePath/Web\ Development/Rails/learning"`

but in the production environment, it needs to be a different path. I want do keep as much as I can under source control (haven't had to give up anything yet). Is there a way to set the `working_directory` based upon the environment?

Answer (score 4):

How are you trying to access RAILS_ENV or RACK_ENV? It should be through "ENV" like...

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV']
```

... or ...

```
ENV['RACK_ENV']
```

One or the other should be available when you pass unicorn the "-E" flag (I can't remember which for sure, but I think it's RACK_ENV).

Comment: Yep, RACK_ENV is available.  RAILS_ENV isn't, AFAICT.

Answer (score 3):

Using `unicorn_rails` makes the environment variables available.

Comment: +1 - This worked for me and solved logging issues where my unicorn.rb was looking at ENV['RAILS_ENV'].

Answer (score 0):

You can access the rails environment with `RAILS_ENV`.

Comment: I don't think that is initialized at that point, I can't seem to use in in config/unicorn.rb

Comment: Have you set the -E flag for unicorn to set RAILS_ENV/RACK_ENV ? see: https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/Documentation/unicorn_rails.1.txt

Comment: Yeah if I run `unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E "development"` then I still get an unitialized constant error when I try to access `RAILS_ENV` or `RACK_ENV`

Comment: and with unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E "development" ? In the worst case you can force the env: RAILs_ENV="development" unicorn_rails ...